# how to turn 3d object into 2d template

Tags: mesh, materials

[image]

how do i turn a shape for example this monkey, into a template like this. (ps im not making a monkey)

Answer (score 2):

It's called "UV unwrapping".
Go to UV editing tab, go into EDIT MODE, select all (A) and press U. then choose one of the method to unwrap the 3d model into 2d.